# find the most common length of text line in a file with various line sizes present using python

Tags: python, string, count

So I am bit stuck thinking over this -

I have a file which contains many character lines - one after the other. They are not in paragraph but rather in this form -

```
xxxxxxx
xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx
xxx
xxxxxxx
xxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxx
xxxxxx
xxxx
xxx
```

The idea is to find the number of lines which has the most common size (or number of characters). In the above example - 4 lines would be the answer

I am trying to do this in python, since the rest of the code is written in it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Please add it to your question.

Comment: sorry I don't have any real code at the moment for this part of the code. My main issue is that the file is being opened somewhere else, and a function is running on each line of the file - then I had to somehow store the length of the line, and find the most common size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter) module has a dictionary subclass named [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) that will could be used to keep track of the length of each line encountered.

This make solving the problem very easy. If the files aren't humongous, you could use it like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common_line_len(filename):
    with open('somefile.txt') as f:
        return Counter(map(len, f.read().splitlines())).most_common(1)[0][0]

print(most_common_line_len('somefile.txt'))  # --> 3 for your sample data
```

Otherwise you could avoid reading it all into memory at once by using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions) in conjunction with a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambdas#lambda) function:

```
def most_common_line_len(filename):
    with open('somefile.txt') as f:
        return Counter(map(lambda line: len(line.rstrip()),
                           (line for line in f))).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Comment: My files are huge to be honest, this is related to biological datasets so the minimum size of a file is about 4gb ...

Comment: So use the second version then, or you could make the function smart and have it decide which technique to use by checking the file size first. The can be done using `st_size` in the `stat_result` the [`os.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=stat#os.stat) function returns.

Comment: thank you - i'll just modify the second bit and use it my case - I know for sure the files will be quite large.

Comment: Actually, if your files are _that_ big, it may not be worth the time it takes to read the whole thing once ahead of time — whether it's all saved in memory at once or not — only to determine the most common line-length.

Comment: my thoughts exactly - ram is a constraint and I was hoping a quick iteration through the file would find the most common line lengths.

Comment: In that case, I think this is likely one of, if not the fastest way to do that. In Python the quickest execution times are often obtained simply by using the built-ins as much as possible.

Comment: I would have gone the route of C or some other dedicated text parsing tools, but the remaining code is sort of written by someone else. So made sense to work it out in python.

Comment: For serious work you might want to consider using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) (Python Data Analysis Library) which I've heard is very good as well as fast, and, of course, there's also [numpy](http://www.numpy.org).

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of lines lengths, then maximize the number of occurances:

```
with open('file.txt') as data:
    length = [len(i) for i in data] # line length
    common = max(length.count(i) for i in length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter and then use counter's `most_common` method:

```
from collections import Counter
with open("a.txt") as f:
    c = Counter(len(line.rstrip("\n")) for line in f)
print(c.most_common(1))
```

Result:

```
[(3, 4)]
```

meaning length 3 is the most common with 4 occurences.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the most common length:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as fin:
    lst = [len(line.strip()) for line in fin]

print max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, starting from reading the lines, there are a few approaches which you could take:

```
myFile = open(path)
for line in file:
    #do something with 'line'
```

or maybe

```
lines = file.readlines()
for i in range(lines.length):
     #do something
```

Then, you'd need to somehow store each line length

```
lengths.append(line.length)
```

Now, you only need to find the most recurrent length

```
frequencies = {}
for length in lengths:
    if length in frequencies: #Check if we already had this length before
        frequencies[length] += 1 #Increment it
    else:
        frequencies[length] = 1 #Add to the list
```

Finding the greatest value from a set should be trivial, but just in case:

```
maximum = 0
for i in frequencies:
    if frequencies[i] > maximum:
        maximum = frequencies[i]
#after this completes, no entry on frequencies is greater than maximum
```